# Identity Server 4 AuthorizationContext.PromptModes empty

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, oidc-client

I am using the [oidc-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-client) library to authorize with our own [Identity Server 4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io). It is working fine and I need to extend the login functionality. I'd like to use the OIDC-Parameter "prompt". The parameter is sent correctly to the connect/authorize endpoint. When the Login-Method is called, I am trying to get the AuthorizationContext by calling

```
        var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(vm.ReturnUrl);
        var prompt = context.PromptModes;
```

_interaction is an instance of IIdentityServerInteractionService. The PromptModes are always empty. Is this the right way I am trying to access them?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you check the value in an inappropriate place.
The answer for a [similar question on Github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/5002) was:

> we have to remove the prompt parameter because we would otherwise run into an endless loop. You could save the parameter in a separate parameter I guess.